# I designed a box with an energy infinite object, is this possible?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I developed my question, Below is a special box with no gravity and vacuum. Let this box be of infinite length. Here an object moves at a speed of 50m / s. If the object has energy here, would we have produced infinite energy. ? Or while this object is pushed by a person, did the energy lost by man turn into the speed that the object gained? Energy does not turn into speed, but there are points that confuse me.

[image]

Comment: *"An object moves with the energy it has"* - But kinetic energy isn't a property of the object, correct? Put another way, two observers in relative uniform motion don't agree on the kinetic energy associated with the object.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri 
I do not fully understand, you say that Energy is not a feature of the body. At the same time, an object moving at a constant speed does not lose its energy. I perceive the concept of energy as a concept of fuel.

Comment: If you are sitting at home, or sitting in a car going 50 km/h, do you feel the same? If yes, then the energy associated to your speed is not part of you. Kinetic energy is not like fuel. Taking that analogy, in a very un-physical manner, kinetic energy is like the amount of fuel you burned to get to a certain movement. Aka, kinetic energy is for example 2L of gas that you burned to get to 50km/h. Not more, not less, and is finite

Comment: @José Andrade 
I updated my question, did you not get the energy when you say? Is the speed just changing?

Comment: I'm closing this post (v3) as non-mainstream as a physical box cannot have infinite length.

Comment: @Qmechanic Roger that

Answer (score 2):

> If the object has energy here, would we have produced infinite energy.
> ?

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "producing infinite energy". but with respect to an observer at rest in the reference frame of the box (the inertial frame of the box) the object has kinetic energy of $\frac{mv^2}{2}$ by virtue of its speed. It is finite, not infinite. But if there is no resistance to its motion then it will theoretically maintain this energy indefinitely, i.e., it would not be dissipated.

If the object was initially at rest in the box, it would have had to acquire its kinetic energy from another energy source transferring energy to the box in the form of work. The principle at play is the work energy theorem which states:

*The net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.*

> Or while this object is pushed by a person, did the energy lost by man
> turn into the speed that the object gained?

Yes, due to the man doing work on the object. If a person pushed the object starting at rest in the box with a constant force of $F$ over a distance $d$, then according to the work energy theorem the person would have transferred energy to the object in the form of work $W$ where

$$W=Fd=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$

> Energy does not turn into speed, but there are points that confuse me.

Energy transfer can produce speed. Work is energy transfer. When the person did work on the object he transferred energy from himself to the object increasing its speed and therefore increasing its kinetic energy, according to the work energy theorem.

> Here, logically, both the presence of motion and the existence of an
> endless energy confuse me.

Now I think I understand your problem. You think it requires energy for something to keep moving at constant velocity. That would be true if you needed to keep applying a force and perform work to overcome an opposing resistance force, such as air friction, in order to keep it moving. That's the case when you drive your car at constant velocity. You need energy (fuel) to overcome all the friction forces at work opposing your motion (air resistance, tire rolling resistance, mechanical friction in the drive train, etc.). If those friction forces did not exist, the only energy you would need is that to get it up to speed (accelerate the car). Once at speed, if the car had no opposing resistance you could turn the engine off and it would run forever at that speed (and given kinetic energy), just like the object in your infinite box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with what you say, but the only place I don't understand. "But if there is no resistance to its motion then it will theoretically maintain this energy infinitely, i.e., it would not be dissipated." This section provides energy movement, but does not decrease or end. Here, logically, both the presence of motion and the existence of an endless energy confuse me.

Comment: First, I meant to say "indefinitely" not "infinitely". I will edit that. Regarding the rest, I think I now understand your problem. I have addressed it in a revision to my answer. Hope it helps.